# SwipeRefreshLayout + NestedScrollView: Data cannot be refreshed

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I encountered a problem using SwipeRefreshLayout + NestedScrollView. The problem is that when everything is OK (every item of the app can be loaded with no crash and swipe-refresh can be done), the data cannot be renewed. However, when I restart the app, new data (from an API) can be loaded which means that data is fine. My `MainActivity.java` and `activity_main.xml` as follow, respectively:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <RelativeLayout
         ...
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

...

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    scrollView = (NestedScrollView)findViewById(R.id.nested_scroll_view);
...
```

Though I have looked up relevant information, I still feel puzzled. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont find you making any refreshing operation in onRefresh().

Comment: @InsaneDeveloper Eh...I am not familiar with these things and new to programming... Can you clarify that?

Comment: Okay. Let's take a case where some data is fetched from API and shown in ListView. So, I want to implement SwipeRefresh, I will hit the api again in  the onRefresh(). and update the adapter with the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late, but for people who still come across this problem

Save/Reset state of ReyclerView before/after adding new item

// Save state

```
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;  
recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
```

// Restore state

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```